# How does JWT token validation work if we are setting user details in SecurityContextHolder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, token

I was going through the JWT Code and in JwtRequestFilter-

```
package com.javainuse.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.javainuse.service.JwtUserDetailsService;

import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
            // authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

there is a check that `if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)` only then we are validating the Jwt token. But for the first time when the user will log in, *SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()* will be invoked and the user details will be put in SecurityContextHolder.

So upon every subsequent request, the if condition will fail as SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null. Then how is the token validated?

Answer (score 0):

SecurityContextHolder associates a given SecurityContext **with the current execution thread.** And subsequent requests are handled in different threads.

So `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()` invoked in current thread will not affect threads for the subsequent requests.

From the [source code](https://github.com/DeveloperHuang/Spring-Security-Source-Code/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.java#L98), you can also see that SecurityContextHolder uses the **ThreadLocal** strategy by default.

Comment: So if every request is handled by a separate thread, then could you please tell then what is the purpose of SecurityContext?  And why do we set SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) ?

Comment: Hi, @shm_csgo,
From the provided code, I assume you are trying to build a Springboot web application. In this case, servlet container (like tomcat) will provide a thread pool for incoming requests.  Every time when requests comes, threads will be chose from the pool to handle the requests.

Comment: SecurityContext, as its name, it is a context of the current thread. In logic, there may be many places that you need to get security info (Security info includes user info in your case, like username, email, ...). It will be inconvenient to get security info from the request every time in code so we prefer to set it into the SecurityContext at the beginning of the request thread (In your case, JwtRequestFilter did this). Next time when we want to use the security info in logic, we can get it from the SecurityContext directly.